# Get unique items in laravel pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot

I have pivot table:

```
Schema::create('coach_user', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('coach_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('coach_id')->references('id')->on('coaches')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

How I can receive all user_ids from this table by Eloquent methods? I did it in next way: `DB::table('coach_user')->select('user_id')->distinct()->get()`
but i received next result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 6
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 7
                )

        )

)
```

And I need collection of user_ids, not the collection of stdClasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use relationships for that:

```
User::has('coaches')->get()
```

This query will give you all users who have at least one coach (has `user_id` in the pivot table).

If this relationship is not defined yet, define it:

```
public function coaches()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Coach::class);
}
```